# Convert text data to Date

Tags: sas, date-formatting, proc-sql

I'm reading data from an xlsx file, and there's a column which has text values ('Cancelled','Postponed','1-01-2018'). I want to convert this column into a date type.

I'd prefer to avoid using SAS, and get this done using a PROC SQL if it's possible

I tried using a PROC SQL, but I can't find any place describing valid date functions in SQL that are available in SAS

```
    CREATE TABLE fixed_date AS
        SELECT
            start_date,datepart(end_date) as formatted_date
        FROM
            input_file
        WHERE end_date_validity = 1;
QUIT;
```

I'm expecting a dataset with a column I can do date arithmetic on. I'm currently getting the error:

```
ERROR: Wrong number of arguments for function datepart
```

Comment: Can you show a picture of the first 5 rows of the Excel, the steps for creating `input_file` and the output from `proc contents data=input_file order=varnum;` ?

Comment: For this particular problem, it doesn't make much of a difference whether you use `proc sql` or not. Unless you write a pass-through query to another DBMS, you can only use SAS date and time functions in `proc sql`, and these won't work outside SAS.

Comment: The SAS `datepart` function takes only one argument.  The `datepart` function in a data base such as SQL Server (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) takes two arguments.  Is it possible you posted only a portion of the actual code, and the query is actually being performed as a pass-through ?

Comment: So this is how I did it

    select INPUT(start_date,DDMMYY10.) as start_date FORMAT =DDMMYY10.,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Excel column that has 'mixed' types of data will become character type when imported into SAS.  You will need to create a new column where the rows with a 'date' string will contain the SAS date value, and rows which do not contain a date string will be a missing value -- The `INPUT` function can be used to convert date strings to date values.

For example

```
proc sql;
  create table have (delivery_date char(20));
  insert into have 
    values ('Cancelled') 
    values ('Postponed')
    values ('1-01-2018')
  ;

  create table want as
  select 
    delivery_date as delivery_date_string,                               /* keep column of original data  */
    input (delivery_date, ? mmddyy10.) as delivery_date format=yymmdd10. /* create new column as date value */
  from 
    have
  ;
```

Since you know the `INPUT` will encounter some non-date strings, I have added the question mark (`?`) modifier before the informat (`mmddyy10.`).  The modifier will prevent log NOTEs such as

```
NOTE: Invalid date value
NOTE: Invalid argument to function INPUT. Missing values may be generated.
```

From the documentation for `INPUT`

> ? or ??
>
> specifies the optional question mark (?) and double question mark (??)
>   modifiers that suppress the printing of error messages and input lines
>   when invalid data values are read. The ? modifier suppresses the
>   invalid data message. The ?? modifier suppresses the invalid data
>   message and prevents the automatic variable _ ERROR _ from being set to
>   1 when invalid data is read.

Also, ?? can only be used in a DATA step.